# How to refer to current cell in Librecalc formula

Tags: cells, libreoffice

How am I gonna be able to access the current cell address while in Librecalc formula? e.g. in excel it is like `()` but it seems that it doesn't work in librecalc.

Answer (score 0):

The function Current() provides the momentary result as the formula is being evaluated.

If you are looking for the "current cell address", the function Cell() may assist you.  Helpful options include:

```
Returns the number of the referenced column.
=CELL("COL";D2) returns 4.
```

.

```
Returns the number of the referenced row.
=CELL("ROW";D2) returns 2.
```

.

```
Returns the absolute address of the referenced cell.
=CELL("ADDRESS";D2) returns $D$2.
=CELL("ADDRESS";Sheet3.D2) returns $Sheet3.$D$2.
=CELL("ADDRESS";'X:\dr\test.sxc'#$Sheet1.D2) returns 'file:///X:/dr/test.sxc'#$Sheet1.$D$2.
```

[Complete documentation on Cell() may be found here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#CELL)